# Unable to migrate files in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am unable to migrate a file in Laravel using PHP.

I tried changing the default password and tried looking in `my.cnf` file.
I am new to using Laravel so I'm not sure how to proceed in terms of troubleshooting. When I asked the questions, I was told that Its because `Mysql 8.0` uses a different method of authenticating the connection. I believe its `caching_sha2_password` as the new default.

To make it work with Laravel as far as I know you need

> `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password`

set in your MySQL configuration file. I'm not sure where I should place that or if its

or you can set the flag using the SQL command-line utility

```
mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
[*] - You can find out where the .cnf files are by running

mysqld --help --verbose
```

When I tried to migrate my database here is the error message I received:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server
>   requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select *
>   from information_schema.tables where table_schema = tutorial and
>   table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>
> 661| // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll
>   format the error 662| // message to include the bindings with SQL,
>   which will make this exception a 663| // lot more helpful to the
>   developer instead of just the database's errors. 664| catch (Exception
>   $e) {
>
> 665| throw new QueryException( 666| $query,
>   $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e 667| ); 668| } 669|

Answer (score 0):

check your .env file and then correct by following:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_db_user_name
DB_PASSWORD=your_db_password
```

If it's correctly and still getting error try this:

```
alter user 'username'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password'; would fix it.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe cached by laravel when you tried to change config .env

Run `php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal/Command Prompt
login to your mysql server

`sudo mysql`

i am assuming that your default user is `root`

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Use the same password in your `.env` file then run following command to clear your cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

OR

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Hope this will solve your issue.